# адаптация окна и кнопок

Tags: python, pyqt5, адаптивность

Я изучаю PyQt5 и столкнулся с такой проблемой: необходимо что бы изображение растягивалось вместе с окном, а кнопки встали на место синих прямоугольников и так же изменялись с размерами окна и изображения. [image: .]
Вот мой код. Думал использовать функцию resizeEvent, но пока что не совсем понимаю как ее внедрить.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow 
import sys

class K01(QMainWindow): 
  def __init__(self):  
        super(K01, self).__init__()
        self.w1=QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.w1)

        self.setWindowTitle("!!!")  
        self.setGeometry(200, 100, 720, 405)

        self.picture = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.picture.setGeometry(0, 0, 750, 400)
        self.picture.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("к01осн.png"))
        self.picture.setScaledContents(True)  

        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn.setText("C01")
        self.btn.setFixedWidth(150)
        self.btn.setFixedHeight(60)
        self.btn.setFlat(True)
        self.btn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {color: yellow; "
                                "font: 28pt Times New Roman }")        
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.C01)
        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn1.setText("C02")
        self.btn1.setFixedWidth(150)
        self.btn1.setFixedHeight(60)
        self.btn1.setFlat(True)
        self.btn1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {color: yellow; "
                                "font: 28pt Times New Roman }")  
        self.btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn2.setText("C03")
        self.btn2.setFixedWidth(150)
        self.btn2.setFixedHeight(60)
        self.btn2.setFlat(True)
        self.btn2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {color: yellow; "
                                "font: 28pt Times New Roman }")  
        self.gird=QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.w1)
        self.gird.addWidget(self.picture, 0,0,6,0)

        self.btngird=QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.btngird.addWidget(self.btn, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gird.addLayout(self.btngird, 2, 0)
        self.btngird.setContentsMargins(-100,-100,-100,-100)

        self.btn1gird=QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.btn1gird.addWidget(self.btn1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gird.addLayout(self.btn1gird, 3, 0)

        self.btn2gird=QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.btn2gird.addWidget(self.btn2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gird.addLayout(self.btn2gird, 4, 0)
    def C01 (self):
        self.wK01=sect01()
        self.wK01.show()
    def application():  
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
        window = K01()

        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        application()
```

Comment: Если данный вопрос еще актуален: предоставьте код, который воспроизведет то, что у вас показано на изображении и еще раз хорошо расскажите, что и как должно растягиваться. И прикрепите картинки, которые  вы используете в коде.